# $H^2$ and $C^1$ - Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega$ be a domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ and let $k$ be a constant. Can we tell that  $k \nabla u \in C^1$n
with $u$ solution of the problem $$-\mathrm{div}(k\nabla u)=f \quad \mbox{in } \Omega, u=0 \quad \mbox{on } \partial \Omega,$$
$f\in L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts and can share what you have tried? Regards

Comment: for $k=0$ this is always true. For the other cases you should take a look at the sobolev embedding theorem

Comment: if $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ how we can prouve that $k\nabla u\in C^1$ please. i haven't an argument.

Comment: and if this $u$ is solution of the problem $$-\mathrm{div}(k\nabla u)=f \quad \mbox{on} \Omega, u=0 \quad \mbox{on} \partial \Omega$$ with $f\in L^2(\partial \Omega)$ we can say that $k\nabla u \in ^1?$

Comment: what is now your question? Check sobolev embedding or in the latter case elliptic regularity theory. And to your above question: in general it is false

Comment: i now this embedding but i don't know how i can use it to see if $k\in \nabla u \in C^1$

Comment: The Sobolev embedding won't give you that - read up on elliptic regularity theory as quickbeam2k1 said.

Comment: have you an book who contain this theory?

Comment: Any book that covers the theory of elliptic PDEs should include it. I recommend Brezis' "functional analysis, sobolev spaces and elliptic PDEs" or Gilbarg + Trudinger.

Comment: what does $k\in\nabla u$ mean if $k$ is a constant? But you should edit you question and give a more precise one. You can also find information on elliptic regularity in Evans book on PDE. But this will highly depend on $f$ and your domain. Btw $f$ is not defined on the boundary. However for $f\in L^2$ you will only get $u$ in $H^2$. To deduce from that that $u\in C^2$. You need either sobolev embeddings or you need the DeGiorgi/Nash/Moser iteration technique. But I doubt that you will get such a high regularity for the solution of that pde

Comment: i don't found this theory on brezis (this is the only book what i have) i will be crazy. any one can help me

Comment: Brezis covers regularity theory in chapter 9.6. However as Quickbeam2ki mentioned above, you need more regularity on $f$ to get what you want - I think a counterexample would be $\Omega = (-2,2), k=1, f = 2 \chi_{(-1,1)}$ which has non-differentiable solution $u(x) = \chi_{(-1,1)}(1-x^2)$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis is this function really in $H^2$? Of course Regularity theory tells you so but since $p=2>1$ and $n=1$ we find that the function $u$ is almost everywhere differentiable and hence its derivative should be $u'(x)=\chi_{(-1,1)} -2x$. But if $u$ where in $H^2$ then $u'$ in $H^1$ and hence $u'$ has a continuous representative. This is not the case with the derivative i calculated above. Can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: sorry, you're right - my $u$ is not actually a solution, didn't think that through properly.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\Omega$ is bounded. Consider the problem

$$\tag{P}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
 -\Delta u=f &\mbox{ in $\Omega$} \\
  u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega) &\mbox{ in $\partial\Omega$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

Because $k$ is constant, to answer your question is equivalently to know if $u$ in the problem (P) satisfies $\nabla u\in C^1(\Omega)^n$. For each $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, we can define $S(f)=u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$, where $u$ is the unique solution of (P).

Now the problem is: For which types of $\Omega$ and $f$, we have that $H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)\subset C^1(\Omega)$? or even better $H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)\subset C^1(\overline{\Omega})$?.

For example, if $n=1$ and $f\in C(\overline{\Omega})$, it can be proved that $u\in C^2(\overline{\Omega})$ (see Brezis PDE book chapter 8 and for more general results, take a look in chapter 9).

On the other hand, if $f$ is only $L^2(\Omega)$, you can construct examples of functions satisfying (P) with $\nabla u$ not in $C^1$. I will leave to you the task to construct such example.

Remark 1: To construct a example, try to explore functions defined by various sentences, like $|x|$, and partition of unity.

Comment: This is problaby your third account. For a long time, I have been answering your questions and I still don't see any effort from your part. To remedy this fact, you could try to find such example and post it here in my answer. Also, I suggest you to write together with your questions, the attempts that your have tried in solve it. People here will see that you are trying to solve the problem and will help you.